# Quantstrat in R

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am uploading quanstrat to R and want to run the demo package. However I am getting error messages when installing and the demo won't run either(see below). Do you have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,
Tom

```
install.packages("quantstrat")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/NMRQL123/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> Warning in install.packages :package ‘quantstrat’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
>   2: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

```
demo(package="quantstrat")
```

> "Error: unexpected input in "demo(package="quantstrat")

Comment: The error message is looking for `ggplot2`. Do you have that package installed? Also, `quantstrat` doesn't appear to be in CRAN, did you set the right repo? `install.packages("quantstrat", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`?

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. it seems it WAS the Repo issue. Much appreciated